# How to pass amp-validation for animating divs?

Tags: amp-html, amp-stories

Each time I try to animate something inside a div, i'm getting errors: The attribute 'animate-in-duration/animate-in' may not appear in tag 'div', which i suppose shouldn't happen since provided examples are animated divs as well. How can I fix this? I think that some errors I'm getting may be related to the fact that I'm using pug, but these seem weird even in this case.

```
      div(animate-in="fly-in-left" animate-in-duration="0.5s")
        amp-img(src=`${source}` layout="responsive" width="1" height="1")

      .container.relative(animate-in="fade-in" animate-in-duration="1s")
        amp-fit-text(layout="responsive" max-font-size="28" width="1" height="0.1" ) TEXT
```

Comment: Can you post a code snippet?

Comment: Edited with samples, but there's nothing besides a basic usage

Comment: Can you show a full example of the output you get from your templating system? Otherwise, the documentation here has examples you can copy/paste: https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/visual-effects/amp_story_animations/
Also, please double check the "body > amp-story > amp-story-page > amp-story-grid-layer > your DIV" strict hierarchy.

Comment: It appears that I've overlooked something and those 30+ errors were caused by a single animated div with amp-img placed inside. Thank you for help!